# Excel - Search for string in list

Tags: arrays, excel, string, list

So let's say we have a list of sentences in the cells of column A that may or may not contain names.

```
A1: "The sea was blue" 
A2: "together with Mary" 
A3: "onward and upward" and so on...
```

I want to be able to check if a certain name exist within the entire list with True / False. For example, if I checked `Mary` it would return True. `Joe` would return False.

I've tried a few things, but they only seem to work if the name is the only thing in the cell. I want it to be able to search sentences in the list of cells, I'm just not sure how to proceed.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This searches for the text in a cell (B8 in this example) in the list of sentences (A8:A10). It's surrounded by an IF statement to turn it into TRUE FALSE. SEARCH returns #VALUE if not found, hence use of IFERROR.

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(B8,$A$8:$A$10),0)=1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant using it :

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("Mary",A1)),"true","false") //you get a string value
```

or using it :

```
=if(iserror(find("Mary", lower(A1),1)),0,1) //you get a boolean value
```

Answer (score 0):

If cell B1 holds value being searched i.e. Mary or Joe and A1:A3 holds list then following formula will give desired results.

`=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(" "&B1&" "," "&A1:A3&" ",1))),FALSE,TRUE)`

Or even following shall work if any substring match is fine:

`=COUNTIF(A1:A3,"*"&B1&"*")>0`